# Is it possible to play 1v6 vs AI in Overwatch?

Tags: overwatch

My buddies and I are looking to get some flexibility with practice and self-challenging modes involving the AI in Overwatch.

Can we set up a game somehow where the teams don't have even numbers? If so, with AI, or just vs humans?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes**. Custom Games allow you to completely configure the number of people on each team, including setting up bots on either team. You can also invite people to fill slots on either team, again, including mismatched.

[image: Setting up a game vs 5 hard bastion and a hard zenyatta]

Comment: If you're wondering how this went for me: poorly.

Comment: I don't know what would be worse: 6 Hard Bastions or 6 Hard Winstons :D